# Diff two methods in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-generation

I have an eclipse which generates java code. So if a method is there and is regenerated I want to show the old method and the newly generated one so the user can see the difference. Is this possible?

Comment: HE should already be able to do that through comparison to local history (compare with => local history).  May be your plugin can activate the local history comparison on some action.

Answer (score 1):

If your code generator is the one used by default by EMF, you can copy the generated method, and remove the *@generated* tag to the original one, then simply suffix the copied generated method with *Gen* and keep the *@generated* tag. For instance :

```
/* original code */
public String getName() {
...
}

@generated
public String getNameGen() {
...
}
```

At the next generation only *getNameGen* will me modified and you will be able to compare.

If you are looking to a more general solution to know if the regeneration modified some files, the best way is probably to store you files on a repo (with SVN or Git). After a regeneration filez not in sync will be indicated with graphical decorators and you will be able to use the compare editor to see the differences for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse Kepler, so depending on your version your mileage may vary.

To compare a method with a previously generated version, do the following:

1. Open the class.
2. Show the Outline view (Window->Show View->Outline)
3. Hold CTRL and click on the method you wish to compare.
4. Right click on the highlighted method.
5. Click on "Compare With->Element From Local History"
6. Double click with the revision you wish to compare with.

You'll get a diff window similar to if you were comparing two files.