# Compare two Python methods in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I've recently switched from Eclipse to PyCharm, and I wonder if PyCharm can compare two methods to each other, like [Eclipse can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8708367/4794). So far, my searching has failed.

I have two similar methods, and I want to check exactly what the differences are.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## 1

highlight one function and copy it into the clipboard....

highlight the second function and right click select "compare with clipboard"

## 2

take highlight the first method and hit delete

paste in the second method where the first one was

right click and select "local history"